# How do I make a new Graph class in Sage with extra methods?

Tags: class, inheritance, python, sage

I am writing some code in Sage to do some calculations with Feynman graphs, which are just finite, un-oriented multigraphs with edge-labels.  I need to implement methods such as edge-contraction, which are curiously missing from the class `sage.graphs.graph.Graph`.  But I also want to inherit all the existing graph methods, like e.g. `is_tree`.

Here's the top of the module Feynman.sage that *ought to* attach the new class.

```
from sage.graphs.graph import Graph

class FeynmanGraph(Graph):
    """An unoriented multi-graph with labeled edges"""
    def __init__(self, E=[]):
        self._edges = len(E)

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'A Feynman graph with ' + str(self._edges) + ' edges.'
```

I'm not doing something right.  Although an instantiation of the class yields the correct directory of methods, many of them don't work because

```
'FeynmanGraph' object has no attribute '_backend'
```

I think this has something to do with the way that Sage is just a Pythonic wrapper for some other graph theory package.

Please advise.

Comment: Hi Sammy, you might have better luck posting your question at [ask.sagemath.org](http://ask.sagemath.org/). (I only know how to do such things in Mathematica: If you forgive some self-advertising see [Feynman Diagrams and Symanzik Polynomials](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ScalarFeynmanDiagramsAndSymanzikPolynomials/))

Comment: Also, Edge contraction is just a special case of vertex merging, where you only merge 2 vertices and you preserve the multiplicities. So see `merge_vertices` which is (along with `is_tree`) in [generic_graph.py](http://hg.sagemath.org/sage-main/file/361a4ad7d52c/sage/graphs/generic_graph.py). There's also a [trac about `edge_contract`](http://trac.sagemath.org/sage_trac/ticket/7304), so see the discussion there.

Comment: Finally, not all sage graph objects are just wrappers of other packages.  If you contract a graph from a list of edges, adjacency matrix etc, then you by default create objects that use `SparseGraphBackend` or `DenseGraphBackend`.

Comment: Most of the graph theory stuff in Sage is networkx, which is a graph theory package programmed IN PYTHON.   http://networkx.lanl.gov/

Answer (score 3):

You might simply not be inheriting things correctly. Try inserting this at the beginning of `__init__()`:

```
super().__init__()
```